# Multiple listviews in same layout

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I've to create a layout with thee listviews, I'm unable to attach sample image. Is it possible to populate three listviews with three different adapters in single layout in horizontal manner? Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: yes. You should create 3 different adapter classes for 3 list views. And create 3 list view item layout xml file for each list view items design.

Comment: Hii... What you want to do actully? Do you want Images in your list view with thumbnails? or what?What is your exact requirment?

Comment: @ChintanRathod I want to have all three listviews in single layout file.

Comment: @MitBhatt I don't have to use images, I want to populate three listviews from three different tables from my local database. These listviews will contain only text data. But I want to have all three listviews in a single layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Custom list view.. So may be this site helps you a lot.. If you have any query you can ask. :)

Check this one
[Custom List View](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: This link is very helpful but in this example only one listview is used. I want three different listviews in a single layout.